# MATLAB second axis for colorbar following a convention

Tags: image, matlab, colorbar

i want to make a second axis for the same colorbar of an false color image. the second scale should follow this convention : [new values]   =   Log10([old values]/108000)/-0.4 . i have this code for the first axis:

```
C = 10
hFig = figure('Name','False Color Luminance Map', 'ToolBar','none','MenuBar','none');
% Create/initialize default colormap of jet.
cmap = parula(16); % or 256, 64, 32 or whatever.
% Now make lowest values show up as black.
cmap(1,:) = 0;
% Now make highest values show up as white.
cmap(end,:) = 1;


imshow(J,'Colormap',cmap) % show Image in false color

colorbar % add colorbar


h = colorbar; % define colorbar as variable
caxis auto
y_Scl = (1/C);
yticks = get(h,'YTick');
set(h,'YTickLabel',sprintfc('%g', [yticks.*y_Scl]))
```

in a previous post here i got this lines for an second axis:

```
BarPos = get(hBar1,'position');
ylabel(hBar1,'label','FontSize',12);
haxes = axes('position',BarPos,'color','none','ytick',0:5:15,'ylim',[0 15],'xtick',[]);
```

how can i make the second axis use the the yticks of the first axis as an input for the convention?

EDIT: here is what i came up with. the thing is the values are wrong :/
[image: image with wrong values on the second axis]

```
fname='IMG_0041'; % select target image
C = 1000; % Constant to adjust image
K = 480; % Cameraconstant



RGB = imread([fname, '.tif']);% Read Image as tif
info = imfinfo([fname,'.CR2']); % get Metadata from CR2
x = info.DigitalCamera; % get EXIF
t = getfield(x, 'ExposureTime');% save ExposureTime
f = getfield(x, 'FNumber'); % save FNumber
S = getfield(x, 'ISOSpeedRatings');% save ISOSpeedRatings
date = getfield(x,'DateTimeOriginal'); % save DateTimeOriginal
I = rgb2gray(RGB); % convert Image to greyscale
% N_s = K*(t*S)/power(f,2))*L 
L = power(f,2)/(K*t*S)*C; % calculate L/N_s
J = immultiply(I,L);

hFig = figure('Name','False Color Luminance Map', 'ToolBar','none', 'MenuBar','none');
% Create/initialize default colormap of jet.
cmap = parula(16); % or 256, 64, 32 or whatever.
% Now make lowest values show up as black.
cmap(1,:) = 0;
% Now make highest values show up as white.
cmap(end,:) = 1;


imshow(J,'Colormap',cmap) % show Image in false color

colorbar % add colorbar


h = colorbar; % define colorbar as variable
caxis auto
y_Scl = (1/C);
yticks = get(h,'YTick');
set(h,'YTickLabel',sprintfc('%g', [yticks.*y_Scl]))


BarPos = get(h,'position');
haxes = axes('position',BarPos,'color','none','ylim',[0 150]);
set(haxes,'YTickLabel', sprintfc('%g', log10(yticks.*y_Scl/108000)/-0.4));
```

https://www.sendspace.com/file/39wwm9 -> files for testing the code

Comment: (You are using parula! :happyface: )

Comment: You want a second axis to the colorbar, I am assuming?

Comment: yes and i think i nearly got it but the log values are shifted along the axis for example: 0.2 should be 14.33 0.4 should be 13.57 and so on

Comment: Also, im pretty sure that is not the code to make the figure you show. Can you please make sure you include a [mcve]

Comment: i updated the OP

Comment: i am quit sure that the problem is at this line :   haxes = axes('position',BarPos,'color','none','ylim',[0 150]);